# Ubuntu20.04.6LTS second monitor(external monitor) not detected with nvidia driver installed

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, external-monitor

my computer is HP Zbook G9, i have diabled the secure boot, and the graphics in bios is hybrid graphics（not UMA graphics）

i tried nvidia-driver-525/470/535, the nvidia-smi all show detailed info, but they all cannot detect second monitor when i print  "xrandr", not the driver i installed is nvidia-driver-470

at first i add the nouveau into blacklist, did this cause this problem? or other reason,can someone give some advices? anyway thank you very much!
here are the snip of "xrandr" and "nvidia-smi"

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.04*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.03  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

nvidia-smi

```
zym@zym-hp:~$ nvidia-smi 
Tue Jul 11 14:22:20 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.199.02   Driver Version: 470.199.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T600 Lap...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P8     4W /  N/A |    464MiB /  3914MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1490      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 49MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14440      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                158MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14826      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               58MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16814      G   gnome-control-center                1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17526      G   ...856249215957001225,262144      138MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    136771      G   /proc/self/exe                     47MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

what i before do is

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

// then add these two cmooand
blacklist nouveau               
options nouveau modeset=0

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

ADD（some info may help）

sudo lshw -C display

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:185 memory:83000000-83ffffff memory:6020000000-602fffffff memory:6030000000-6031ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:184 memory:6032000000-6032ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

```
zym@zym-hp:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-76-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-019) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023
```

info in the settings（i cannot paste a picture in it because of low reputation hhh）

```
12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H × 20 
NVIDIA Corporation / NVIDIA T600 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
```